# Clear example and best approach to NSCollectionView

Tags: cocoa, nscollectionview

I looked for this on the web, but I could not find any clear tutorial on how to successfully implement an NSCollectionView. How should I proceed?

In Interface Builder, I can drag an NSCollectionView to the main view, and I see that there are two other new views in the documents window: I suppose one is the actual NSView inside the collectionView, and the other one is the NSView prototype for each of the elements that will be displayed inside the collection.

But from now on I don't have any idea about what to do.

Any help would be very appreciated, but thank you anyway in advance.

—Albé

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode > Help > Developer Documentation...

The Collection View Programming Guide contains a step-by-step tutorial. (In fact, that's all it contains at present.).  The sample app IconCollection is all set up with reasonable bindings and code to show how the collection view works.